# Sealed class generic

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

The below codes working perfectly.

#### Resource

```
sealed class Resource<out T:Any>{
    data class Success<out T:Any> (val data:T):Resource<T>()
    data class Error(val exception: Exception):Resource<Nothing>()
    data class Loading(val message:String):Resource<Nothing>()
}
```

#### Flow structure

```
    fun simple(): Flow<Resource<String>> = flow {
        delay(100)
        emit(Resource.Loading("Loading message..."))
        delay(100)
        emit(Resource.Error(Exception("Error Message")))
        delay(100)
        emit(Resource.Success("Value=X"))
    }

    suspend fun <T> Flow<T>.process(
        onLoading: ((T)->Unit),
        onError: ((T)->Unit),
        onSuccess: ((T)->Unit)) {
        collect { value ->
            when ( value ) {
                is Resource.Error -> {
                    onError(value)
                }
                is Resource.Loading -> {
                    onLoading(value)
                }
                is Resource.Success<*> -> {
                    onSuccess(value)
                }
            }

        }
    }

    fun job1() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            simple().process({

            }, {

            }, {

            })
        }
    }
```

[image]

As you can see from image, all callbacks return `Resource<String>` type. Is it possible to return `Resource.Loading` for `onLoading` callback, return `Resource.Error` for `onError` callback and return `Resource.Success<String>` for `onSuccess` callback?

What I want to achieve is:

```
    fun job1() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            simple().process({Resource.Loading

            }, {Resource.Error

            }, {Resource.Success<String>

            })
        }
    }
```

Another question is compiler forced me to write `Resource.Success<*>`. Otherwise gives error:
Is there any harm in writing like this?

[image]

Edit_1:

```
    suspend fun <T: Resource<Any>> Flow<T>.process(
        onLoading: ((Resource.Loading)->Unit),
        onError: ((Resource.Error)->Unit),
        onSuccess: ((T)->Unit)) {
        collect { value ->
            when ( value ) {
                is Resource.Error -> {
                    onError(value)
                }
                is Resource.Loading -> {
                    onLoading(value)
                }
                is Resource.Success<*> -> {
                    onSuccess(value)
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

[image]

Edit_2

Best i can do, but giving error:

[image]
[image]

Error gone if i cast to ...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood correctly you need to change your `process` method to that

```kotlin
suspend fun <T : Any> Flow<Resource<T>>.process(
    onLoading: ((Resource.Loading) -> Unit),
    onError: ((Resource.Error) -> Unit),
    onSuccess: ((T) -> Unit)
) {
    collect { value ->
        when (value) {
            is Resource.Error -> {
                onError(value)
            }

            is Resource.Loading -> {
                onLoading(value)
            }

            is Resource.Success<*> -> {
                onSuccess(value.data as T)
            }
        }

    }
}
```

https://pl.kotl.in/Ho_gw0q31

---

but if you want to return in the `onSuccess` the whole `Resource.Success` you can do it like that

```kotlin
suspend fun <T : Any> Flow<Resource<T>>.process(
    onLoading: ((Resource.Loading) -> Unit),
    onError: ((Resource.Error) -> Unit),
    onSuccess: ((Resource.Success<T>) -> Unit)
) {
    collect { value ->
        when (value) {
            is Resource.Error -> {
                onError(value)
            }

            is Resource.Loading -> {
                onLoading(value)
            }

            is Resource.Success<T> -> {
                onSuccess(value)
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: but i couldnt access data of Resource.Success. it is returning Resource<String>. please see my edit in question

Comment: ok so in the `onSuccess` you want to get directly the data, you can see the updated version and the ktplayground link @EyeOfTiger

Comment: can you check my cast also? is it ok?

Comment: when i try your code in android studio, giving warning => Unchecked cast: Any to T

Comment: check the latest edit with the extra code to see if this is what you want (with no cast)

Comment: perfectly fit :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean something like:

```
suspend fun Flow<Resource<*>> .process(
    onLoading: ((Resource.Loading)->Unit),
    onError: ((Resource.Error)->Unit),
    onSuccess: ((Resource.Success<*>)->Unit)) {
    collect { value ->
        when ( value ) {
            is Resource.Error -> {
                onError(value)
            }
            is Resource.Loading -> {
                onLoading(value)
            }
            is Resource.Success -> {
                onSuccess(value)
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: BTW are you sure you want to use `collect` and not `onEach` + `.launchIn(scope)`?

Comment: I think you can use a `<T>` for the function and then use `T` in place of `*` so the success listener won’t have to cast the result type.

Comment: @kingston just simulation purposes i used collect

Comment: @Tenfour04 i updated my question according your answer(please see edit_1). But it is returning Resource<String>. Is it also possible to change this to Resorce.Success<String>?